# XAML cannot reach localized resources

Tags: c#, wpf, localization, resources

I'm having trouble with localized resources for sub-projects.

The main project (called Z) uses subproject (called ProjectsModule), which has its own resources. The subproject has two resource files:

```
Strings.resx
Strings.pl-PL.resx
```

The application is running in debug mode with Polish as current UI culture.

I'm getting the following exception:

```
System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException: 'Operacja podawania wartości elementu 
„System.Windows.Markup.StaticExtension” wywołała wyjątek., numer wiersza 24, pozycja 52.'
ArgumentException: Obiektu StaticExtension 
„ProjectsModule.Resources.Strings.Projects_Config_Projects” nie można rozpoznać jako wyliczenia, pola 
statycznego ani właściwości statycznej.
```

Translated, it says:

```
"ProjectsModule.Resources.Strings.Projects_Config_Projects" cannot be recognized as enum, static field
or static property.
```

This happens, when window's XAML is loaded. So I did a test and modified window's constructor:

```cs
public ConfigurationWindow(ConfigurationWindowViewModel viewModel)
{
    // *** DEBUG ***
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ProjectsModule.Resources.Strings.Projects_Config_Projects);
    // *** END DEBUG ***

    InitializeComponent();

    this.viewModel = viewModel;
    viewModel.Access = this;
    this.DataContext = viewModel;
}
```

And strangely I'm getting the following output:

```
Katalogi projektów
'Z.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Z.exe): Loaded     'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xaml.resources\v4.0_4.0.0.0_pl_b77a5c561934e089\System.Xaml.resources.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentException' in System.Xaml.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Xaml.XamlObjectWriterException' in System.Xaml.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException' in PresentationFramework.dll
Operacja podawania wartości elementu „System.Windows.Markup.StaticExtension” wywołała wyjątek., numer wiersza 24, pozycja 52.
```

The "Katalogi projektów" is exactly the resource I'm looking for - so it is clearly reachable. However, for some reason it is not reachable by the XAML parser (you can see the exception mentioned earlier just after properly resolved resource).

What am I doing wrong? Why the resource, which clearly is available (and, moreover, read from proper translated satellite assembly) is not available by the XAML parser?

---

**Edit:**  In response to comments

Resource usage:

```xml
<Window ...
    xmlns:properties="clr-namespace:ProjectsModule.Resources"
</Window>

...

<TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Top" Margin="3" Style="{StaticResource Header}" 
    Text="{x:Static properties:Strings.Projects_Config_Projects}"></TextBlock>
```

Culture is based on operating system culture. So it is set automatically.

Comment: Can you show where you use the resource in XAML and where you set the culture?

Comment: @thatguy, edited post.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> StaticExtension value cannot be resolved to an enumeration, static field, or static property.

Your `.resx` files must have a `Public` access modifier, otherwise you will get a `XamlParseException` at runtime, since the XAML parser cannot access the resources. It is `Internal` by default, so resources cannot be accessed from another assembly. To change the access modifier, go to the resource editor and change it in the header drop-down menu.

[image]

Alternatively, change the `CustomTool` in the resource file properties to `PublicResXFileCodeGenerator`.

[image]

Comment: Weirdly, when there were no satellite assemblies, internal worked perfectly. But indeed, switching to public worked. Thanks!